# Finding the associated matrix of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension $n$ with a scalar product, and let $u$ be an unitary vector in $V$. Let $H_u: V \to V$ be defined as

$$H_u(v) = v - 2 \langle v,u \rangle u$$

for all $v \in V$. I need to find the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial of this linear operator, but the only way I know to find the charactestic polynomial is using the associated matrix of the operator.

I don't know how to find this matrix because I don't know how to deal with the scalar product. Is there some other way to find the characteristic polynomial? If not, how can I find the associated matrix of this linear operator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\langle v, u \rangle$ defined as ?  Since this will help determine the matrix.

Comment: [Since you have already asked this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/528783/78926), and you even got an answer there, it is not polite to ask the same question again. If you have trouble with the answer, comment it. If your question needs changing, edit it. But don't create copies of an answered question.

Comment: @VedranŠego Do you realize that I wouldn't get any other answer to the question in the first post? And do you realize that the answer is too elaborated and difficult to understand for a beginner? I'm glad I posted it again because now I got easier approaches in this post.

Comment: @EnjoysMath it's just a scalar product, there isn't an explicit formula for it.

Answer (score 2):

$H_{u}=I-2P_{u}$, where $P_{u}:v\mapsto\left\langle v,u\right\rangle u$
is the projection onto the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $u$.
Decompose the space as $V=\mathbb{C}u\oplus\left(V-\mathbb{C}u\right)$,
then

$$
P_{u}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0_{n-1}
\end{array}\right]
$$
and 
$$
H_{u}=I_{n}-2P_{u}=I_{n}-2\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0_{n-1}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0\\
0 & I_{n-1}
\end{array}\right]
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left\langle \nu',H_{u}\left(\nu\right)\right\rangle
=
\left\langle \nu', \nu\right\rangle
-
2\left\langle \nu, u\right\rangle
\left\langle \nu', u\right\rangle
$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider an orthonormal basis containing $u$ and express $H$ in that basis.